# How should I design my activity table?

Tags: php, mysql

I made a "follow system". The DB design looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_followers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'auto incrementing USER_FOLLOWER_ID for each row unique index',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'foriegn key to UserId column in users table',
  `follower_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'foriegn key to UserId column in users table',
  `follower_since_timestamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'timestamp of the follow'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Before the follow system, all inputs/post/entries were visible to all. Going on a big feed/wall. Now with a couple 100 users it is hard to navigate.

Should I do it the way it was before: 1)check if I follow a user and fetch all information or should I future proof it and make an activity table?: 2)Check if i follow a user, look at the activity table and fetch the appropriate data from post table.

With the activity table it seems I can have a much bigger overview of what's going on. I could *for example* have a column `deleted`, but the data is still there in `post`.

Is an activity table necessary?

Comment: This question falls under mostly as *"Primarily opinion-based"*. You'll probably get a better response if you posted on Database Administrators Stack Exchange http://dba.stackexchange.com/ - Not my downvote, but did vote to close as such.

Comment: You're welcome Adam.

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing my two cents, I built a system that enable researchers (well users of the system) to follow each other based on the study of interest, I did it exactly the way you proposed, it really made it easy to pull out data from the data, like for example if User A has a study interest of JavaScript, I can easily use the user_id of User A in table Activity, to pull areas of interest of User A, I hope you get what I am trying to say tho?

Comment: Yes thats my opinion also and thoughts on how to use activity table